# Pandoc ignoring --resource-path flag for relative image locations

Tags: command-line, pandoc

I'm using Pandoc to convert a `.DOCX` help document to `.MD`, using something along the lines of

`pandoc --extract-media="c:\help\document\output" -f docx -t markdown_mmd "c:\help\document\input\Document Name.docx" -o "c:\help\Document\output\Document Name.md" --resource-path="/media"`

In the .MD file I expect to see multiple instances of `<img src="media/image1.png"` but instead the paths are all absolute; e.g. `<img src="c:\help\Document\output/media/image1.png"`

Reading the Pandoc guide, if I use `--extract-media` with `--resource-path` I should be able to specify a relative path for the images, but it's not working.

What do I need to pass into the Pandoc command to ensure the image folder and images are relative to the `.MD` file's location?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to make your output directory to your current directory e.g. to quickly open the results by Notepad++.

On Windows using File Explorer go to the folder and type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open PowerShell. Or your preferred method to open a command window or PowerShell e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right mouse click for context menu ...

Following pandoc command is resulting in the expected result (see screenshot below):

`pandoc -f docx -t markdown_mmd "d:\help\document\input\my-word-document-name.docx" -o "./my-word-document-name.md"  --extract-media=.`

When using the current directory as path DIR, then a folder `media` is created within the current directory.

[image]